# Unset "visited" pseudo class in Safari

Tags: safari

I'm doing some development, and I can't figure out how to un-set the "visited" flag after clicking on a link in Safari. I've tried clicking on/off the `:visited` selector in the Web Inspector, emptying the cash, and removing the destination from browser history, but the link is still has the `a:visited` style applied.

This is Safari 16.1 on Mac OS Ventura 13.0.1.

Comment: It isn't a `flag`.  Have you tried deleting the history entirely to confirm you aren't missing sonething.

Comment: I had not, but I have now, and it's still showing all links as having been visited.